# Setting up CocoaMQTT in Swift doesn't work

Tags: swift, mqtt

```
import Foundation
import CocoaMQTT

func mqtt_con() {
    let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
    let mqtt5 = CocoaMQTT5(clientID: clientID, host: "broker.emqx.io", port: 1883)

    let connectProperties = MqttConnectProperties()
    connectProperties.topicAliasMaximum = 0
    connectProperties.sessionExpiryInterval = 0
    connectProperties.receiveMaximum = 100
    connectProperties.maximumPacketSize = 500
    mqtt5.connectProperties = connectProperties

    mqtt5.username = "test"
    mqtt5.password = "public"
    mqtt5.willMessage = CocoaMQTTWill(topic: "/will", message: "dieout")
    mqtt5.keepAlive = 60
    mqtt5.delegate = self
    mqtt5.connect()
}
```

Here is my code to set up a simple Mqtt client in Swift. It throws the Errors:"Cannot find 'CocoaMQTTWill' in scope" & "Cannot find 'self' in scope". I don't know where's my fault.

Comment: What is `self` in your sample code? Currently it's not inside an object, so there is no `self`.

Comment: It's exactly the example from the corresponding GitHub Repository (https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT)

Comment: `self` is specific. There is no "context" on the sample code, because it's assummed to be inside an object. Concerning `CocoaMQTTWill` I don't know, but the `self` has a meaning in Swift.

Comment: Check the implementation in the example source: https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT/blob/master/Example/Example/ViewController.swift

Comment: I'm using SwiftUI and don't know how to wrap this example to SwiftUI.